Calcular y guardar la antigüedad en años en MYSQL con PHP
Buenass, estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde tengo que calcular la antigüedad de los empleados en años apartir de una fecha dada "ingreso" y que la edad se vaya actualizado conforme a la fecha local, posteriormente guardar los años en la BD. EL ejecutar el proceso solo se queda en blanco.
function ingresar (){
  include("../fechas/config.php");
$ingreso=trim($_POST['ingreso']);
$fecha_nac = strtotime($ingreso);

  $edad = date('Y', $fecha_nac);
   if (($mes = (date('m') - date('m', $fecha_nac))) < 0) {
    $edad++;
   } elseif ($mes == 0 && date('d') - date('d', $fecha_nac) < 0) {
    $edad++;
   }
   $antiguedad= date('Y') - $edad;

   $antiguedad=$_POST['antiguedad'];
$sql="UPDATE empleado SET antiguedad='$antiguedad";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);


tienes errores de sintaxis: "UPDATE empleado SET antiguedad='$antiguedad" si estas grabando un INT deberia de ser :  "UPDATE empleado SET antiguedad=$antiguedad"

si se graba vacio, verifica el valor de $antiguedad algo como var_export($antiguedad) deberia mostrar lo que pretendes guardar ...

Creo que tú modelo podría mejorar si guardas directamente el campo de fecha de ingreso en el usuario. Así, cuando tengas que mostrar la antigüedad, podrás calcularla con esa fecha y la fecha actual. Sino, cuando necesites mostrar la antigüedad estará desfasada(en tú modelo)

Nunca guardes un diferencial (como la edad) en tu db.. deberias recalcularlo para todos todos los dias...

Te aconsejo un monton estudies los Campos Autocalculados algunos los llaman Virtuales, estan presentes en muchas bases de Datos Mysql, SQL SERVER etc, que hace este campo calculado, tu le indicas que el valor que debe tener ese campo es un calculo de otros campos del mismo registro, entonces por ejemplo si quieres calcular antiguedad puedes agregar modificando la tabla este ejemplo para calcular dicha Antiguedad:
ADD COLUMN antiguedad_anios INT AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fecha_ingreso, CURDATE())) VIRTUAL;```

... Continuando con mi comentario estos campos lo puedes usar para calcular cualquier cosa, vencimientos de documentos, edades lo que tu quieras sin tener que crear programas o rutinas que lo hagan y esta directo en base de datos y su valor se actualiza de forma automatica, apentas realices cualquier intervencion en la TABLA, ya sea consultas, inserciones o modificaciones.

El el caso de campos calculados (el total de una venta, un total general, una edad, la antigüedad de un empleado, etc.) no es recomendable guardarlos en la BD. Es mejor realizar el cálculo cuando lo necesites.
En un sistema de empleados es obligatorio almacenar la fecha de ingreso a la empresa (y, generalmente, la de nacimiento). En base a esa fecha puedes calcular la antigüedad al realizar tu consulta:
SELECT fecha_ingreso,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fecha, CURDATE()) AS antiguedad_años,
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(fecha_ingreso, INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fecha_ingreso, CURDATE()) YEAR)) AS dias
FROM tabla
WHERE id_empleado = 'id_empleado'

De esta manera puedes tener la antigüedad (o la edad de un empleado, si en lugar de la fecha de ingreso usas la fecha de nacimiento).
